# IntelliJ integration test folder alongside main and test

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot, maven-3, integration-testing

I want to add some integration tests to a spring boot application. The resulting structure would be this

```
MyProject
├── myapp.iml
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── integration-test (integration test sources root)
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── mysite
    │   │           └── myapp
    │   │               └── AppTestIT.java
    │   └── integration-test.iml
    │
    ├── main (sources root)
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── mysite
    │   │           └── myapp
    │   │               └── App.java
    │   └── main.iml
    │
    └── test (test sources root)
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── mysite
        │           └── myapp
        │               └── AppTest.java
        └── test.iml
```

Is this possible? I'm doing this in `Intellij 15 Ultimate` and it doesn't recognise the package as `com.mysite.myapp` in my integration tests. Instead it recognises this `java.com.mysite.myapp`. It doesn't follow the convention as it does with `main` and `test`, which is expected. Is there a way to add more folders alongside `main` and `test` and follow the same conventions (java folder not taken into consideration for the package declaration)? 
If not, what is the best practice regarding the project structure when including integration tests? Should they be in the test folder? I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should be as easy as right clicking the `integration-test` folder, scrolling down to "Mark Directory As..." and selecting "Test Sources Root".

Note that if you have other developers working on this project they will have to do the same thing (unless you share IDEA files).

Comment: For my project structure is the java folder. Still a valid answer though. Thanks

Comment: How do you do this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 23):

The correct way in this case would be to change the Maven configuration appropriately, so that it also works when executing the build on command line (e.g. on a build server etc.). You can do this by configuring the build-helper-maven-plugin:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-test-source</id>
        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

IntelliJ picks up this configuration and marks the folder automatically as test source folder.